# Why does this General Linear Model think random Negative Binomal values have a slope?

Tags: python, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm just exploring Generalized Linear Models for the first time, and trying to see if I can correctly fit the simplest model I can think of. So I'm generating random values from some NegativeBinomial distribution and then fitting it with a GLM.

```py
np.random.seed(5555555)
weeks = np.arange(np.datetime64("2020-01-01"),np.datetime64("2022-12-01"),np.timedelta64(1,'W'))
counts = pd.Series(nbinom.rvs(10, .5, size=weeks.shape[0]))
counts.index=weeks
obs, last = counts[0:-1], counts[-1:]

X = np.array(obs.index.values.tolist())
X = np.stack((X, np.ones(X.shape[0])),axis=1)
X.shape
y = obs
mdl = GLM(y, X, family=NegativeBinomialFamily())
results = mdl.fit()
results.summary()
```

I would think that the slope for my one independent variable of 'date' should just be 0.

But this code always gives me a very small positive value:

```
 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results Dep. Variable:     y   No. Observations:   152


Model:  GLM     Df Residuals:   151
Model Family:   NegativeBinomial    Df Model:   0
Link Function:  Log     Scale:  1.0000
Method:     IRLS    Log-Likelihood:     -504.15
Date:   Thu, 04 May 2023    Deviance:   28.334
Time:   10:51:39    Pearson chi2:   24.8
No. Iterations:     4   Pseudo R-squ. (CS):     -0.001740


Covariance Type:    nonrobust

coef  std           err         z       P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
x1    1.396e-18     5.25e-20    26.594  0.000   1.29e-18    1.5e-18
const   8.594e-37   3.23e-38    26.594  0.000   7.96e-37    9.23e-37
```

What's going on here? It looks like the model is very confident the model has an itty bitty positive slope.

Am I setting up the model wrong? Am I interpreting the output wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the `1.405e-18`?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. shouldn't that be 0? Or maybe something small because of random sampling, but 0 should be in the confidence interval?

Comment: Can you please re-run your code with a [specified RNG seed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) and give us the results so it is reproducible? Thanks!

Comment: The tiny value for the parameter estimate is expected. What is less expected is the large z value and the tiny p value.

Comment: that makes sense, @StephanKolassa, but why the tiny P? Its _very_ confident there's a slope there. (if slope is the right way to think about it for a GLM?)

Comment: oh, and its always positive. I have run this lots of times (with no seed), and it always comes up about the same.

Comment: Perhaps you are not considering how actually small the number `1.405e-18` is. This is smaller than the amount of precision you can expect for floating point numbers (e-16 usually), and so for all practical purposes this is equivalent to zero. (See these questions for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24847918/10930406 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: Thanks @Kuku. That's a good point. But wouldn't I expect it to at least vary _around_ 0, if i run it multiple times? Anyway, it sounds like there isn't something clearly wrong with how I'm running the model, its just some quirk of the random values or floating point math, as you say.

Comment: @kuku You confuse size with precision.  That p-value has a representational precision of 52 bits, just as any IEEE double precision number does provided it's not too tiny (around $10^{-308}$).  It likely has some imprecision introduced by the numerical algorithm, but generally we can expect 8 - 13 decimal digits of precision in any p-value *regardless of its size.*  This value is *not* "equivalent to zero" for all practical purposes, because sometimes such purposes combine that value with others in ways that make even such a tiny value of material importance.

Comment: Nate, by expressing your question in code you make it inaccessible to anyone not conversant with the language and willing to run your code.  That's a severe limitation of the audience.  It would be better to explain what you want the code to do and to state explicitly, clearly, and fully why you think its output might be incorrect or surprising.

Comment: oh! I think it has  to do with using np.datetime64 values as the independent variable. If I swap weeks with just np.arange(200), i get x1s that flop around 0, and the P value is big.

Comment: @whuber It's not clear to me that a p-value will actually have the precision you state; typically an optimization algorithm will stop at some precision far short of that (for good reason), and subsequently calculations that depend on that optimization will not have any higher precision. Consequently we might just be dealing with the particular conditions under which the `GLM` function decides to stop when trying to optimize parameter estimates.

Comment: @whuber I stand corrected, thanks. Perhaps a small correction though is that I was not referring to the p-value but rather to the standardized coefficient `std` (if I'm reading the python output correctly).

Comment: @Glen_b That is true for some algorithms, especially with p-values.  Fortunately, precision of p-values is almost always immaterial: two decimal places is usually more than enough.  My point stands: no matter what the reported number might be, as far as the computer representation is concerned, it has a full 52 bits of precision unless it is denormalized (and therefore has a magnitude smaller than c. $2^{-1022}\approx 10^{-308}$).